# Fake proof that $\cot^4 x = -\tan^4 x$

Tags: integration, fake-proofs

What am I missing?

Consider:
$$ \int \frac{x^4}{\left(1-x^2\right)^{5/2}} dx$$

If we let $x = \sin \theta$ we get

$$ \int \frac{\sin^4 \theta}{\cos^5 \theta} \cos \theta d\theta$$

as $dx = \cos \theta d\theta$. We can simplify the above expression to

$$ \int \tan^4 \theta d \theta$$

However, if we let $x = \cos \theta$ we get

$$ -\int \frac{\cos^4 \theta}{\sin^5 \theta} \sin \theta$$

as $dx = - \sin \theta d\theta$.

We can simplify the above expression to

$$ -\int \cot^4 \theta d\theta$$

Now, the two simplified expressions are equal since they are equal to the original expression. So we have the following equality:

$$ \int \tan^4 \theta d\theta = -\int \cot^4 \theta d\theta$$
$$ \frac{d}{d\theta} \int \tan^4 \theta d\theta = \frac{d}{d\theta}\left( -\int \cot^4 \theta d\theta\right)$$

The derivative of the integral is the same as the function so

$$\tan^4 \theta = -\cot^4 \theta$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $\theta$s in the two susbtitutions are two variables, say $\theta$ and $\theta^\prime:=\pi/2-\theta$ so $\cot^4\theta^\prime=\tan^4\theta$. The extra $-$ sign follows from $d\theta^\prime=-d\theta$.